# filtering data using .keypress - no plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I am trying to filter data using .keypress. My current approach is to capture the data from .keypress and pass to my filter function. I am successful in returning data that begins with a letter. So if I type A into my field it will return all cats that begin with A. I would like to narrow my search by typing in more letters and have it update each time. Is there a simple solution here? Here is the code

// retrieve data from key press

```
$("input").keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
                    var criteria = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode|e.charCode);
                }
                $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                    filterCats(cats, criteria);
                });
            });
```

// filter function

```
            function filterCats(cats, criteria){
            $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
                //var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) !== -1;});   
                var filteredData = cats.filter(function(c){return c.breed.toUpperCase().indexOf(criteria.toUpperCase()) === 0 ;});    
                renderData(filteredData);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Use the value of the input instead of the keypress: `var criteria = $(this).val();`

Comment: How would you like to narrow it? first of all using `keyup` event is more accurate for your filtering, second you can get the length of your input and compare it to your desire threshold. Is that what you want? Also do what `Andy` said

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi I would like to filter it so that as I type in letters the data updates. So if I am searching for orange in array = {oral, orange} I type in oran and oral will vanish from my data. That's a silly example but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: @00robinette Still, your code will only try to filter by _one_ letter instead of the entire string value.  Andy is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, `keyup` is better because it fires after the key is released.

> **keydown**
>
> Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keypress**
>
> Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
>
> **keyup**
>
> Fires when the user releases a key, after the default action of that key has been performed.

Above from http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Also as the other answer states, running your code immediately after every key press could result in a lot of requests sent to the server.

Instead, try throttling it with a timeout.

```
var timeout, criteria;
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        criteria = this.value;
        $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
            filterCats(cats, criteria);
        });
    }.bind(this), 125);
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

As Andy pointed out in a comment, you need to use the value of the input, since you are currently looking at a single character upon each character entry. As Hossein Shahsahebi pointed out, `keyup` would be a more accurate event for what you desire to do. Also, do not forget about pasting, which should trigger the same logic.

I would like to add that I believe it is undesirable to do the searching upon each character entry. Imagine someone typing really quickly. You will have a lot of requests sent to the server. I would rather wait for a while before doing the search. When the event is triggered, store the current time in a variable and use `setTimeout` to wait for a second or so before calling the `filterCats` `function`. Whenever the event runs, override that variable to the current moment. When `filterCats` is executed, check whether the variable's value is old-enough. If not, return without filtering. If so, do the filtering. This will decrease server load due to this feature drastically.